# GWT-RPC в Ecplipse

Tags: gwt, rpc, java, eclipse

Разбираемся с GWT 2.4 на Eclipse 3.7. GWT Designer действительно хорошая вещь, GUI делается достаточно удобно и быстро. Возникают проблемы с RPC, [инструкция на google](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) не соответствует версии eclipse 3.7 (генерируемый код eclipse при добавлении rpc-клиента отличается от инструкции на google, насколько я понимаю, там этот процесс более автоматизирован), если честно, там не очень понятно написано.
В NetBeans 7, например, добавление клиента веб-службы делается довольно просто.
*Время просто поджимает, поэтому прошу дать инструкцию (на простом примере) от создания проекта до просмотра на броузере работающего приложения.*

Comment: Многие действия из примеров google в eclipse 3.7 делаются автоматически по команде Google Web ToolKit -> GWT remote service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я начинал с этого (StockWatcher project tutorial).

[http://code.google.com/intl/ru/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/RPC.html](http://)